# Ignore crack in Android screen (and entire front panel) or take some action

Tags: screen, hardware

My Galaxy S3 was in my jeans pocket when I leaned over to pick something up that I dropped under the table. A few minutes later, when I took out my phone, I saw a long diagonal crack from one side of the phone, straight through the middle of the screen area and all the way to the further edge of the phone.
Thankfully everything still works.

My question is, is there anything I should do about it - i.e. replace the screen, layer it with transparent tape - or just leave it and everything will be fine (i.e. it can't get worse)?

Answer (score 2):

Lots of screens are cracked and they still work.  Mine has had two cracks in it for over a year.  At first I put thin non glossy mending tape on each crack.  It was unnecessary no glass sticks out on it though I can feel them with a fingernail, so I just leave it bare.  For anything worse and still working you might use a screen protector, which I'd certainly do if the alternative was getting cuts on my fingers.  Would be interesting what your experience actually was as has been several months since you posted.

Comment: Good idea. Shortly after I wrote this question I placed a screen protector over the screen and it's worked completely as normal since then.